# Can't access Coturn web interface

Tags: webrtc, rfc5766turnserver, coturn

I have a running coturn instance on Centos-7-x64, if I access it through the browser I can see:

> **TURN Server**
>   ***use https connection for the admin session***

After examining the documentation, I found this:

> Add the admin user(s) to the database, with turnadmin utility. If you added those users, **then they will be able to connect to the TURN server ports over HTTPS from your browser and perform admin tasks with the web interface**.

So I created an admin user with the following command:

```
$ sudo bin/turnadmin -A -u username -p password
```

And I can see that user listed when running:

```
turnadmin -L
```

However, when I try to connect to https://my.ip.adrss:3478 I can't see the promised admin.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure TLS. For this, you can start the server with the following flags (taken from documentation)

> --cert    Certificate file, PEM format. Same file 
>               search rules applied as for the configuration 
>               file. If both --no-tls and --no-dtls options 
>               are specified, then this parameter is not needed.
>               Default value is turn_server_cert.pem.
>
> --pkey    Private key file, PEM format. Same file 
>               search rules applied as for the configuration 
>               file. If both --no-tls and --no-dtls options 
>               are specified, then this parameter is not needed.
>               Default value is turn_server_pkey.pem.

You'll need to specify the path to each file. You can find the file with `find / -name turn_server_*.pem -type f`, if you want to use the ones that the package comes with. Otherwise, you can point to your own files. I think they are located in `/etc/turn_server_cert.pem` and `/etc/turn_server_pkey.pem`

Comment: @shlomi-schwartz Did you check this?

Comment: thank you for your help. I had to generate the keys myself, but your solution works for me

Comment: @rightaway717 Can you please provide steps for creating PEM file?

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried your solution, but still not working. I'm getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I've tried with my certificate which are working and also with coturn example certificate, but the result is the same. Could it be something else?